# Gravity Forms, how to link form to amember pro signup

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms, membership

Trying to linkup a custom gravity form to my aMember Pro signup form and having difficulties.

I have this for my in my functions file:

```
// Gravity Forms to aMember Pro Link Up

add_action("gform_after_submission_5", "after_submission", 10, 2); // Run these scripts strictly on Form ID 5
function post_to_third_party($entry, $form) {

    $post_url = 'https://www.domain.com/amember/signup/index/c/cart/';
    $body = array(
        'name_f' => $entry['3'],
        'name_l' => $entry['4'],
        'email' => $entry['1'],
        'login' => $entry['2'],
        'pass' => $entry['5']
        );

    $request = new WP_Http();
    $response = $request->post($post_url, array('body' => $body));

}
```

I have tried the post_url as 1. https://www.domain.com/amember/signup/index/c/cart/ 2. https://www.domain.com/amember/signup/index/c/ and 3. https://www.domain.com/amember/signup/

with no luck. Wondering if anyone here has tried to link these 2 systems up. Found threads online but haven't been that helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code (as is) will never call your `post_to_third_party` function.  The `add_action` hook needs to reference that function like so:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_5", "post_to_third_party", 10, 2);
```

Hope that helps, have fun!